# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getFieldByName'

Tags: python

Another Python newbie question, but I can't find an answer by Googling.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  for dbTrack in db.execute('SELECT * FROM tracks'):
     genre  = dbTrack.getFieldByName(genre)
     artist = dbTrack.getFieldByName(artist)
     album  = dbTrack.getFieldByName(album)
     title  = dbTrack.getFieldByName(title)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/personal/Python/Mp3Gen/test.py", line 207, in <module>
    genre  = dbTrack.getFieldByName(genre)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'getFieldByName'
```

---

[Update]  `db` is from `db = sqlite3.connect(SQLITE_DATABSE_NAME)`

How do I go about getting those fields?  `dbTrack = {tuple}(None, 'The Verve Pipe', 'Villains', 'The Freshmen')`  Do I just use `dbTracks[0]`, etc?

I agree with @ abarnert that that is not good practice. I would not do it in any other programming language, but being so new to Python, I can't seem to find how to `getFieldByName`

Comment: `dtTrack` is a tuple, not whatever you are thinking it is. Without knowing what exactly `db` is, it's hard to tell you any more than that, except that you probably want to put those field names in quotes (`"genre"`, `"artist"`, etc.).

Comment: just log the content of `dbTrack`, you'll see what it looks like, and why it is not that object with that method you want to call

Comment: Why did you think the SQL result rows would have a `getFieldByName()` method? You probably can just use `genre, artist, album, title = dbTrack` here.

Comment: if you are doing this in the intepreter, run a `dir(dbTrack)` to list the methods that dbTrack has, you will notice `getFieldByName` is not one of them. Also you did not google this, i just googled it and about 37,200  results came up

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That's relying on the order (and number) of columns returned by `*`, which is at best not robust, and in theory not even guaranteed to work in the first place (although in practice you'll get away with it with sqlite).

Comment: @abarnert: as I said, you *probably* can. Most databases do order columns, and `SELECT *` honours that ordering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, any Python database library that meets the [DB-API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) standard will give you some kind of sequence for each row, usually a tuple or list. (In `sqlite3`, it's a tuple.) Obviously you can't call methods like `getFieldByName` on a tuple or list.

Even though it isn't part of the standard, many libraries provide a way to specify a [`row_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory), and may provide built-in alternative row factories. For example, [`sqlite3.Row`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Row) allows you to access it as if it were a tuple, or a dict (using the column names as keys).

So, most likely, you copied and pasted your code from some other program that uses custom a row type that has a `getFieldByName` method, but you didn't copy the code that sets that custom row type as the row factory.

---

As a side note, even if you fix this, this line isn't going to work:

```
 genre = dbTrack.getFieldByName(genre)
```

At this point, the variable `genre` either doesn't exist (in which case it'll raise an `UnboundLocalError` or `NameError`), or has some irrelevant value. You almost certainly wanted the literal string `'genre'`.

---

If you're using sqlite3, I think you'd be a lot better off using its built-in `Row` type than some custom type that's more verbose and not standardized, wherever it comes from. So:

```
db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

# ...

for dbTrack in db.execute('SELECT * FROM tracks'):
    genre  = dbTrack['genre']
    artist = dbTrack['artist']
    album  = dbTrack['album']
    title  = dbTrack['title']
```